# Sending multipart mails and attachments

Tags: ruby, email, email-attachments, multipart

I am trying to send an E-Mail using the gem 'mail' with Ruby 1.9.3. It contains an text/html and an text/plain part which should be embedded as alternative parts as well an attachment.

This is my current code:

```
require 'mail'

mail = Mail.new
mail.delivery_method :sendmail
mail.sender = "me@example.com"
mail.to = "someguy@example.com"
mail.subject = "Multipart Test"
mail.content_type = "multipart/mixed"

html_part = Mail::Part.new do
  content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
  body "<h1>HTML</h1>"
end

text_part = Mail::Part.new do
  body "TEXT"
end

mail.part :content_type => "multipart/alternative" do |p|
  p.html_part = html_part
  p.text_part = text_part
end

mail.add_file :filename => "file.txt", :content => "FILE"

mail.deliver!
```

It results in an mail with working alternative parts but no attachment. I am using thunderbird 10.0.12 for testing.

I already posted this on github, but unfortunately the posts don't make me smarter. https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/118#issuecomment-12276876. Maybe somebody is able to understand the last post a bit better than me ;)

Is somebody able to get this example working?

Thanks,
krissi

Comment: Have you tried using attachments? For instance: mail.attachments['myfile'] = .....

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work in this scenario either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug regarding the content type of the attachment. See https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/522

Answer (score 4):

I managed to fix it like so:

```rb
html_part = Mail::Part.new do
  content_type  'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
  body          html
end

text_part = Mail::Part.new do
  body          text
end

mail.part :content_type => "multipart/alternative" do |p|
  p.html_part = html_part
  p.text_part = text_part
end


mail.attachments['some.xml'] = {content: Base64.encode64(theXML), transfer_encoding: :base64}
mail.attachments['some.pdf'] = thePDF

mail.content_type = mail.content_type.gsub('alternative', 'mixed')
mail.charset= 'UTF-8'
mail.content_transfer_encoding = 'quoted-printable'
```

Not intuitive at all, but reading the [Pony](https://github.com/benprew/pony/blob/master/lib/pony.rb) source code kinda helped, as well as comparing a working .eml to whatever this gem was generating.